# error while accessing dll written in c through jna

Tags: c, dll, jna

I have written a dll in C an now accessing the functions inside dll through jna on 32 bit windows but it is throwing the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to
>   load library 'mydll': The specified module could not be found. at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:164) at
>   com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:237) at
>   com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.(Library.java:140) at
>   com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:375) at
>   com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:360) at
>   CLibrary.(DllTest.java:6) at DllTest.main(DllTest.java:19)

Whereas the same dll ( made for 64 bit) is working fine on 64 bit, the issue is with 32 bit dll on 32 bit system

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: cdecl or stdcall? in 32-bit platform you need to care about that. in 64-bit platform there is single calling convention

Comment: hi now on adding _stdcall i am able to load the library properly but still it is unable to find the exported function. I am not using any imort library and header file and I am using eclipse

Comment: You probably need to use a [`StdCallFunctionMapper`](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#my-library-mapping-causes-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror).